# Highlight TD cell for date time

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui

I had asked the question earlier for a similar problem. I have a simple JavaScript to highlight a date text in a TD cell. I had to change the date format to "24/04/2015 10:57 AM" and screwed up my script. I tried adapting it to my new date format but its not working. I have a td cell with the class as "SM_next_update".

What I am trying to accomplish is to highlight a cell when the date time is overdue. It will highlight orange when its 15 minutes about to expire and red when its overdue.

Would anyone know what I am missing?

```
$('.SM_next_update').each(function () {
    var dtSt = $(this).html().split(" ");
    var dtAr = dtSt[0].split("/");
    var when = new Date(dtAr[1] + "/" + dtAr[0] + "/" + dtAr[2] + " " + dtSt[1]);
    console.log(when);    
    var new = new Date();

    if (when.getTime() - new.getTime() < 900000 && new < when) {
        $(this).addClass('min30');
    } else {
        if (new > when) {
            $(this).addClass('min60');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: you should change new to newTime, since new is a keyword.

Also what do console.log(when) and console.log(new) output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used a reserved word for your variable name.

Other than that, it works:

```
$('.SM_next_update').each(function () {
    var dtSt = $(this).html().split(" ");
    var dtAr = dtSt[0].split("/");
    var when = new Date(dtAr[1] + "/" + dtAr[0] + "/" + dtAr[2] + " " + dtSt[1]);
    console.log(when);    
    var current = new Date();

    if (when.getTime() - current.getTime() < 900000 && current < when) {
        $(this).addClass('min30');
    } else {
        if (current > when) {
            $(this).addClass('min60');
        }
    }
});
```

You can see a [demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p5jo32zx/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Have you see the console for errors on runtime? Because new is a reserved keyword and you are using it as a nariable name and that is probably throwing an error. Also if the issue persist please provide the text value of a $('.SM_next_update') element

Comment: There is an example of the text in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Couple things you should try first:

1. Change var new to something else as new is a keyword.  var newTime (or now, current, etc)
2. You should remove the previous class if you're adding a new one as well.

   ```
   $(this).removeClass('min30').addClass('min60');
   ```

Just in case there are css conficts, it keeps it cleaner.

3. Change

   ```
   else {
       if (){}
   }
   ```

   to

   ```
   else if (){}
   ```

It's just a lot cleaner, and functionally the exact same. That's just semantics though.